# Hive table or view? Which should be the right approach?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am new to HDFS/HIVE. Need some advice. I have a background of RDBMS Data modelling.

I have a requirement of a daily report. The report requires fetching of data from two staging Tables(HIVE).

What if I create a table in HIVE, write a view to fetch records from staging to populate HIVE table. create a HIVE view pointing to HIVE table with where clause of selecting one-day data?

1. HIVE staging tables ---> 2. View to populate HIVE table --> 3. HIVE table ----> 4. View to fetch data from HIVE table created in 3.

what if I create a view on top of two staging HIVE tables (joining two tables with where clause to fetch one-day data)?

1. HIVE staging tables --->  2. View to fetch data from HIVE staging tables

I want to know HIVE best practice and solution strategies.

Answer (score 1):

View or not View but you need ETL process to load tables. ETL process can join, aggregate, etc, so you will be able use finally joined and aggregated data in the form star/snowflake or report table. Why do you need Views here? To reuse some common queries, to reduce complexity of some long complex queries, make interfaces to data, create logical entities, etc. You do not necessarily need View simply to join tables and load data to another table. All depends on your requirements. If reports should query data fast then data should be precalculated by ETL process. View is just wrapper over query, it will be calculated each time you query data.

Comment: The view will have some transformation logic. It is not a simple one to one mapping. There are some calculations/derivations in between. That's the reason I have mentioned a view to populate HIVE table. You can consider it as ETL process.

Comment: View is the last stage of ETL? It may be better to materialize your final View and create a table because querying table is faster, and ETL process that will load materialized table can be scheduled when the load not critical and reports will query data faster.

Comment: If your data access pattern is write one - read many times you definitely should materialize your join in Hive table. Join on big data tables can be quite costly in terms of time and cluster resources.

Answer (score 1):

I think its best if you have zero views, 1 single table, and make your partition the date field (but you can't partition on the date, so you have to store it as a string) ... this make it easier for the end user to have only 1 table... fewer tables.

This gives your users the ability to engage only the latest date they want, or leverage the full table.